# Best way to maintain Account context in URL

Tags: php, symfony

For an app I am working on, all of the URLs have the current account number in the URL:

- GET /123456
- GET /123456/catalog/products
- GET /123456/catalog/products/blue-bear

I also have some URLs that do not need to know about the current Account:

- GET /profile
- GET /profile/accounts

I have an event listener (`onKernelRequest`) to retrieve the Account from the repository using the account number and set it as an attribute on the Request:

```
$event->getRequest()->attributes->set('account', $account);
```

This allows me to inject the Account into my controller actions:

```
public function getAction(Account $account)
{
    $priceBook = $account->>getPriceBook();

    // ...
}
```

In the same listener, I also set the account_number on the Router context:

```
$this->router->setParameter('account_number', $account->getAccountNumber());
```

This allows me to generate the routes without always passing the Account:

```
{{ path('app_product_get', { 'product_id': 123 }) }}
```

I also set the Account in the session to handle the times when the User visits the /profile pages and n longer has the account_number in the URL:

```
$event->getRequest()->getSession()->setParameter('account_number', $account->getAccountNumber());
```

Is this the best way to do this or should I create a service that "holds" the current Account object as a property? Am I doing too much in one listener?

Comment: If the account id is bound to the URL anyway, your solution looks reasonable. However, you can still simplify it by [creating a param converter](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter) which doesn't force you to create your own event listener (depending on your model it might be possible that you do not even need to create your own param converter).

Comment: Thanks, @xabbuh. I have updated the question with some further info.  I thought of using a ParamConverter but wasn't sure I could/should access the route and session from there.

Comment: I am just wondering what happens when you try to access a URL containing an account ID that is different from the one stored in the session. How do you deal with that?

Comment: If the User has access to that Account, then the context is changed.  Otherwise, I throw a 404.